# Regex in Vim misses second out of two matches in first pass, requires second pass

Tags: regex, vim

Using Vim 7.4 on Windows, I am trying to remove unnecessary spaces before and after parentheses from code in a C file; example:

```
copyFunc ( copyLength, sizeof ( type ) );
```

The following pattern removes a space before a closing parenthesis:

```
:%s/\(\S\) )/\1)/g
```

I was surprised to find out that the above pattern removed the first space immediately following `type` in the above line, but skipped the next one, between the final two successive closing parentheses `) )` at the end of the line.

```
copyFunc ( copyLength, sizeof ( type) );
                                     ^
                                     Not removed on first pass
```

Please note that I am not looking for a workaround solution.  Rather, I am interested in understanding the cause of this regex behavior.

Comment: The first replace consumes up to the first `)`, which can't be used to match `\S` in the next match. If vim implements them you could use a look-ahead to test the presence of a parenthesis without consuming it. Or you could refrain from matching a character before the space, which would change the behaviour for multiple spaces and start of lines

Comment: @Aaron I think I understand.  After the first match, the matching process continues from the space before the final closing parenthesis.  The pattern is three characters long, and the final three characters in the line do not satisfy the pattern.  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes this is right

Comment: @Aaron Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid endless recursions (and because it generally makes sense), `:substitute`'s `/g` flag only considers **text not yet matched** for further iterations on a line of text.

Your the literal `)` in your pattern `\(\S\) )` matches the closing parenthesis; therefore, it cannot match again (this time as `\S`) in further iterations.

One way to fix this is by ending the match *before* the closing parenthesis. This can be done with a *positive look-ahead*, or easier (in Vim) by ending the match with `\ze`:

```
:s/\(\S\) \ze)/\1/g
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you!  Now I need to learn the "how" in detail. :)